# Creating an empty collection of Outlook.Items

Tags: vba, collections, outlook

I have a vba macro code in which I do something like this:

```
Dim myFoundItems As Outlook.Items
Set myFoundItems = myCalendars.Restrict("[customUserProperty] = '" & sId & "'")
```

Where customUserProperty is user property that I am adding in my macro (few lines after that restriction). However on first run of this macro I get an error that property doesn't exist. So I am thinking about setting the error handler that will set myFoundItems to empty collection. However I cannot achieve this in any way!

I've tried using below code, however it causes another error!

```
Set myFoundItems = New Collection
```

Maybe you know how to set myFoundItems to empty collection or even a better way to check if UserProperty is already created?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new Items instance using the New keyword. Instead, you have to use the Items property of the Folder class.

The cause of the issue is that you can't reference a user property using just the name in the filter query. Instead, you have to use a DASL query like the following one (VBA):

```
criteria = "@SQL=" _ 
  & Chr(34) & "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/" _ 
  & "{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/customUserProperty" & Chr(34) _ 
  & " = 'Microsoft'"
```

See [Filtering Items Using Query Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869374.aspx) for more information. You may also find the [Office Developer: How to programmatically restrict or filter “To” property using Outlook Object Model?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deva/archive/2013/04/10/office-developer-how-to-programmatically-restrict-or-filter-to-property-using-outlook-object-model.aspx) page helpful.